# ExpressCard SSD continusouly indexing

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, spotlight, indexing

I've had a 48GB SSD in my ExpressCard slot on my '09 17" MBP for the last 8-9 months and haven't had a problem up until this past week.  When I look at spotlight it says that it is indexing the SSD, and it won't stop.  I've left the laptop on over the weekend and I come back and its doing the same thing.

Is there a way to fix this?  If there is no obvious method, is there a way to at least turn of indexing for this drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest [yet not only] way to prevent Spotlight indexing a drive is...

1. Connect the volume or drive you want excluded to your Mac.
2. Open the System Preferences application.
3. Click on Spotlight, then click on the Privacy tab.
4. Drag your volume or drive into the Privacy menu to exclude it.